# SQL: Alter tables returned from a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How to alter the tables and drop constraints returned as strings from a Select statement?

Let's say I have a database that contains tables: tblA, tblB, tblC, among others.
If I run a query to select tables that meet a certain criteria, it returns the following:

```
+------------+------------+
| table_name | constraints|
+------------+------------+
| tblA       | consX      |
+------------+------------+
| tblB       | consY      |
+------------+------------+
| tblC       | consZ      |
+------------+------------+
```

Now I want to alter each table and drop their constraint. So for example instead of having to write a select statement, get the results, and type this in:

```
alter table tblA drop constraint consX; 
alter table tblB drop constraint consY;
alter table tblC drop constraint consZ;
```

How can I do all those steps in one query?

Thanks.

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL, which is highly vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Sorry, I added Oracle in my tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
with table_list as
( select 'Foo1' tname from dual
  union
  select 'Foo2' tname from dual
)
select 'alter table ' || tname || ' drop constraint ' || constraint_name || ';'
from user_constraints, table_list
where user_constraints.table_name = tname;
```

this will create a string built as an alter statement for each table/constraint. Add
the table names to query in the WITH clause.  Note that the USER_CONSTRAINTS only lists constraints for the current schema.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the variables using what I used in my example? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using PL/SQL, I would do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_query IS --REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR ACTUAL QUERY
    SELECT tableName, conName
    FROM dual;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c_query LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||rec.tableName||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||rec.conName;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```